# How To maintain Code versioning with Salesforce DX?

Tags: salesforcedx, versioning

I wanted to know how can one maintain Code versioning with Salesfroce DX.

Comment: With a separate tool like Git. If you're new to Salesforce (or a part thereof), then https://trailhead.salesforce.com is going to be the better resource for your initial learning.

Answer (score 2):

You should be using a version control system as your source of truth. This is well-covered on Trailhead:

- [Git and GitHub Basics](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/modules/git-and-git-hub-basics)
- [Develop an App with Salesforce CLI and Version Control](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/projects/develop-app-with-salesforce-cli-and-source-control)

Answer (score 1):

In regards to API versions, make sure that the sourceApiVersion field in your sfdx-project.json file is set correctly. All metadata pulled should be in that version. When you're ready to update, change the sourceApiVersion, and use:

```
sfdx force:source:retrieve -p force-app/
```

To update all the files to the newest version.